# Animating one animated component as a user clicks on it from a flatlist of data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-native

Hi so I have a flatlist that creates a certain list with a button on each list. When a user clicks on a button, that one button the user clicks on should animate. As of now, I can only animate all buttons in the flatlist, not just that one I need. Any suggestions? here is my implementation example so far. don't worry about spelling too much, I'm more worried about the logic. THanks guys!

```
  renderAnimation(post, index, item) {
     return (
       <View>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
             this.setState({ likesButton: true })
         }}>
      <Animatable.Image
      animation={this.state.likesButton ? "bounce" : null}
      duration={3000}
    />
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     );
   }

<Flatlist 
dataSource={this.state.data}
renderItem={({item, index}) => { 
<View>
{this.renderAnimation()}
</View>
}}
/>
```

so this animates all the buttons on the list when a user clicks on one. but I just want that one button to animate the user clicks on, not all

Comment: It looks like this.state.likesButton belongs to the component rendering the entire flat list not just the button clicked?  Also see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#extradata as it may be of use to you.  It tells flat list to pay attention to more data than just the data causing renderItems to render.

Answer (score 0):

so I was able to solve this by doing something hacky. I basically animate using the flatlist which renders all items, then I rendered null on all the other none selected items in the flatlist, then I rerenedered those items again to give the appearance that just one selected item was rendered with the animation.